# Moving library files to main project in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-library

I am using opensource OI ShoppingList template and trying to modify it from http://www.openintents.org/.

There are two Libraries and one main project, I am trying to move the libraries to main project which is "OI ShoppingList" but it gives me error in code.

I managed to move one of them without problems "ShoppingListLibrary". I had no problems moving  DistributionLibrary, but when I move layout files ("oi_distribution_eula", "oi_distribution_infoactivity") to main project 3 source files broke.

Any ideas what I should change to make this work been searching everywhere but no luck.

Here is dropbox link to source. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iisqncajbbd9gel/ShoppingList-source-1.6%20not%20working.rar

Thanks in advance

edit1: thanks for the feedback. Here is one of the codes the error is in setContentView(R.layout.oi_distribution_infoactivity);

under the layout the error reads "layout cannot be resolved or is not a field"

I have tried importing R class, cleaning the project but still i have that error

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDistribution.setFirst(MENU_DISTRIBUTION_START, DIALOG_DISTRIBUTION_START);

    // Check whether EULA has been accepted
    // or information about new version can be presented.
    if (mDistribution.showEulaOrNewVersion()) {
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.oi_distribution_infoactivity);

    init();

    mApplicationStrings = new String[mApplications.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mApplications.length; i++) {
        mApplicationStrings[i] = getString(mApplications[i]);
    }
    setListAdapter(new FontArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mApplicationStrings));
    ListView listview = getListView();

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // Set message of activity
    String appname = VersionUtils.getApplicationName(this);
    String message = getString(R.string.oi_distribution_info_activity_text, 
            appname);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(message);

    /*
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(mTheme, R.styleable.ShoppingList);
    String typefaceName = a.getString(R.styleable.ShoppingList_textTypeface);
    mTextSizeMedium = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.ShoppingList_textSizeMedium, 23);
    mTextSizeLarge = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.ShoppingList_textSizeLarge, 28);
    mTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ShoppingList_textColor, Color.BLACK);
    Drawable background = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.ShoppingList_background);


    View v = findViewById(R.id.background);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

    mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), typefaceName);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    tv.setTextSize(mTextSizeMedium);
    tv.setTextColor(mTextColor);
    */
}
```

Comment: You should not expect users here to download and attempt to compile your code. Post short and relevant snippets of code along with any errors you are receiving.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an error in your resources somewhere (it could be in a layout, it could be a drawable or string) that is preventing `R` from getting generated properly. Go through your resources and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: I tried alot but everything started breaking so I left it as it is. Thanks for the help

Comment: why would you move this libraries to your project like that, for best practices, import each library as an element of your project (in project properties), and if you want to modify or add things, just do that directly on library